# Netbeans JFrame getting a button to link to a text box

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I'm doing a huge project for my programming fundamentals course to make a menu for a beauty salon and I'm pretty much done with the code to make it work, but i want to make a graphical user interface to go with it so I'm using Jframes. I'm making a jField with 7 buttons that i'm going to configure in my vector/container to put their answers in a text field to their right, the only thing is

1. I don't know how to get the button to use/run the code and put it in the text box to the right of it and
2. How can i make it so the text boxes only put the answer I've and
   can't edited, because right now if I go to preview design the text
   boxes can be edited (or am i stupid and this doesn't need a text box
   instead it needs something else?) this is the code for first buttons
   code I've made (but any example how to connect a button to a
   textbox(?) to the code in a javaclass file is fine)

   ```
           public void orderAscendingByPrice(){
           Reciept aux;
           for (int i=0; i< quantity ; i ++){ 
           for(int j=i+1 ; j< quantity; j ++){
           if (VecG[i].getTotalIncome()>VecG [j].getTotalIncome()){

           aux=VecG[i];
           VecG[i]=VecG[j];
           VecG [j]= aux;
           }}}}
   ```

   Here's a link to the image because since I'm a real novice at programming i doubt i can answer any questions to get enough rep to post an image... https://www.dropbox.com/s/lctg3v44gzxz94t/Netbeans%20project%20help.png?dl=0
   Hope you guys can help and sorry i can't put an image like this but i've been searching the internet for hours to find help and have found nothing with my particular problems...

Comment: [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: thanks that has helped some in figuring out what i need to do :)

Comment: If you have further issues, don't hesitate to post a new question with what you have tried, effort is always rewarded ;)